# Adding margin between elements in a react list inside a react infinity loader

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized, react-window

Is there any way I can add a **gap** between elements in a  react-window-list inside a n infinity loader? Setting a margin doesn't work.

I found how to do that in the following way:

```
margin: 10px 0;
height: 50px !important;
```

I found this solution quite horrible, is there other way to do that?

ps: setting **`itemSize`** 50 instead of setting it in the css doesn't work.

Comment: Could you show us what the html looks like so we can see what you’re trying?

Comment: I just follow the secon example from here https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window-infinite-loader, I just adde a style on the row element